# How to Get data from another class in swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, class, swift3

I have one swift file and in which I have kept my common function that I need every time so when I am accessing that function I am not getting value

**Myfirst class**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class test1
{
    var mydata = NSMutableArray()


    //MY COMMON FUNCTION

    func loadMoredata(create_at:String)->NSMutableArray
    {
        **//////My CODE**
        //getting correct data
         print(mydata)
         return mydata
    } 
}
```

**Mysecond Class**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
        //Calling that function
        // not getting data here or empty array
        let dt:NSMutableArray = test1().loadMoredata(create_at: "0")

        // not getting data here or empty array
        print(test1().mydata)
}
```

Comment: Does the first class retrieve data from the network?

Comment: yes Paulw11 the first class receive data fro webservice

Comment: could you show more of the `loadMoredata` function? There should be some `asynchronous` code in there what is not handled properly.

Comment: describe your question more clear, did you mean you want to get the class1's data?

Comment: Yes sir I want to get data from class1

Comment: You need to show more code, but it seems very likely that you are trying to return from within a network operation completion handler; you can't do this as this code is invoked asynchronously.  You will need to pass a closure to `loadMoreData` and have the function invoke that in order to pass the data back

Answer (score 0):

You dont get anything back from your function since your `mydata` property is an instance property. Hence, every `test1` object you create, will have its own `mydata` property with its own data.

If you want store global state you could make `test1` a singleton class, where `mydata` is globally accessible.

```
class test1
{
   static let shared = test1()
   var mydata = NSMutableArray()

   private init(){}


   //MY COMMON FUNCTION

   func loadMoredata(create_at:String)->NSMutableArray
   {
       **//////My CODE**
       //getting correct data
        print(mydata)
        return mydata
   }
}
```

Comment: No still getting empty array while calling this function from other class

Comment: Even though you do 'test1. shared. loadMoredata( create_at: "0" )' you still get an empty array? You must do something wrong within the 'loadMoredata()' method then. Can you post your code for further information pls?